# Webcam Pixel Manipulation/Sorting via Processing

Tags: java, processing, webcam, pixel, webcam-capture

I am attempting to write a Processing sketch that will take each row's center pixel's color and apply that color to the entire row. However, I am having trouble with even getting the pixels to change. It seems like the sketch doesn't even go through the for-loops where I am trying to change the pixels because it doesn't print out any of the statements except the `end draw` at the end of `draw()`. I just end up with an unmanipulated feed. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Also, currently using Processing's standard Video library with Capture at the moment, but if there is a better library that I could utilize please let me know! Thanks!

*UPDATE:* Testing out my algorithm with an array of numbers, it seems like using an inner for loop isn't working like how I thought it should. The `i` of the outer-loop is only incremented once after the first time the inner for loop completes itself, and then it just exits the outer loop instead of starting the inner loop again. What's going on here?

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture feed; // webcam

int pixelCount = width * height; // total # of pixels
int center = width / 2; // value for center pixel
int widthPlus = width + 1; // value to go row-to-row

color c; // center pixel color

void setup(){

  size(displayWidth, displayHeight);

  feed = new Capture(this);
  feed.start();
}

void draw(){

  if (feed.available() == true){
    feed.read();
  }

  image(feed, 0, 0);
  feed.loadPixels(); // load pixels from webcam

  /** Use to look at each row one at a time*/
  for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i+=widthPlus){
    println("Outer for-loop");
    c = feed.pixels[i + center]; //get center pixel

    /** Make each pixel in row the color of 'c' */
    for (int j = i; j < width; j++){
      println("Inner for-loop");
      feed.pixels[j] = c; // set pixel to 'c'
      println(i + " - " + j);
    }
  }

  feed.updatePixels(); // update pixels from webcam
  println("end draw"); 
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of code missing. How do you set width and height? Are you sure they aren't 0 when you try to draw?

Comment: `width` and `height` are constants in Processing, so currently my width is 1280 and my height is 800. These are the same as `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` which are also constants in Processing, so they are taken from my actual display.